# Access viewpager's fragment from activity

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a `tabLayout` inside my activity. When the tabs are clicked, it shows a `viewpager` which contains a fragment. I am trying to get reference to the viewpager's fragment but i get a `null pointer` every time. How do i get an instance of the viewPager's fragment from the activity?

Method One: `Fragment fragment = new Fragment();`

Method Two: `Fragment fragment = (Fragment) viewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(viewPager, viewPager.getCurrentItem());`

**ViewPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private int no_of_tabs;
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int no_of_tabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.no_of_tabs = no_of_tabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new Fragment();

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return no_of_tabs;
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        final ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        final TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        firebaseFirestore.collection("Categories")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, document.getString("title") + " => " + document.getData());
                                tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(document.getString("title")));
                                tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
                                final PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
                                fragment = (Fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager + ":" + viewPager.getCurrentItem());
                                viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
                                fragment.setTextViewText();
                                viewPager.setAdapter(categoriesPagerAdapter);
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());


            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
      Fragment page = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewpager + ":" + viewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

Replace `R.id.viewpager` with your viewpager id

You cannot use this code inside `onCreate` method because fragments UI are not yet created.

In this case, you can do this

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4); // this forces to load 4
```

`setOffscreenPageLimit` is used to force the adapter to create 4 more pages after creating the first one. The default value is 1. This is only useful to access a non selected page.

If you need to update your fragments UI while a page is created, then you can use this in `onCreate`...

```
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(x);    
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {
            // here you can set you UI values from page 'i'.
            // i = page index 
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            // here you can set you UI values from the selected page
            // i = page index 
            // for the first selected page (before scrolling), use onPageScrolled
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {
        }
    });
```

The first time a `viewpager` fragment is showed, the `onPageSelected` is not fired but `onPageScrolled` does. So, you can play with these 2 methods to update your fragments UI.

Comment: i still get a null pointer when i try to get a method from the fragment

Comment: Are you sure your fragment is already created? where are you getting the fragment instance?

Comment: inside my viewPager. please review my question and code

Comment: ok, but where in your activity would you like to reference your fragment. My code is valid for the currently selected page. If you would like to reference a non selected page, then this is probably not yet created.

Comment: am doing it in the activity's onCreate method. i still get a lot of errors

Comment: can i use an interface instead?

Comment: `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` doesn't use those tags.

Comment: ok, @Catholic Readings, in the `onCreate` method, `viewpager` pages are not yet created. `Adapter` is created but fragments UI do not because the `Activity` has not finishing his own UI creation. Let me edit my answer...

Comment: please see my edited code. i dont know why i still get errors

Comment: This is not the right way to do that. You are creating a new Adapter continuously inside a `for` loop. The Adapter should be created only once, and then you can update your adapter document list. On the other hand, `addOnTabSelectedListener` is not needed. You can use `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);`. With these function, your `viewpager` is synchronized with your `tabLayout`.